# adding custom function to summarise in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this, with different observations for each `id`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3), v1= rnorm(8), v2=rnorm(8))
```

I then group by `id`:

```
by_id <- group_by(df, id)
```

Now I want to calculate mean and sd of the observations of `v1` for each `id`. This is easy with `summarise`:

```
df2 <- summarise(by_id,
                    v1.mean=mean(v1),
                    v1.sd=sd(v1))
```

Now I want to add the slope of a linear regression of `v1` and `v2`

```
df2 <- summarise(by_id,
                   v1.mean=mean(v1),
                   v1.sd=sd(v1),
                   slope=as.vector(coef(lm(v1~v2,na.action="na.omit")[2])))
```

However, this fails, I think because one person (id=3) has only one observation and thus cannot build a linear model.

I also tried

```
   slope=ifelse(n()==1,0,as.vector(coef(lm(v1~v2,na.action="na.omit")[2]))))
```

but it does not work either. Is there an easy solution for this?

Not that it may also be the case that if I have more than one observation but for example `v2` has a missing value, so the `lm` might also fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try this

```
group_by(df, id) %>% do(fit = lm(v1~v2, .)) %>% summarise(intercept = coef(fit)[1],  slope= coef(fit)[2])
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

   intercept     slope
1 -0.3116880 0.2698022
2 -1.2303663 0.4949600
3  0.3169372        NA
```

note the use of `do` and `.` inside the `lm` function.

Comment: thanks, it works as is, but not when I also include `mean=mean(v1)` in the summarise

Comment: no, because I am passing `fit` (linear model) in `summarise` not the original   `data.frame`. For the mean you can use your own code and then use `cbind` to concatenate the result with this solution.